# How to pass custom type array to Postgres function

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql

I have a custom type

```
CREATE TYPE mytype as (id uuid, amount numeric(13,4));
```

I want to pass it to a function with the following signature:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myschema.myfunction(id uuid, mytypes mytype[])
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS...
```

How can I call this in postgres query and inevitably from PHP?

Comment: select myschema.myfunc('0d6311cc-0d74-4a32-8cf9-87835651e1ee'
       , ARRAY[('ac747f0e-93d4-43a9-bc5b-09df06593239', '25.00')
                              , ('6449fb3b-844e-440e-8973-31eb6bbefc81', '10.00')]::mytype[]
                      );
still need php though!

Answer (score 11):

You can use the alternative syntax with a [**array literal**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) instead of the array constructor, which is a Postgres function-like construct and may cause trouble when you need to pass *values* - like in a prepared statement:

```
SELECT myschema.myfunc('0d6311cc-0d74-4a32-8cf9-87835651e1ee'
                  , '{"(0d6311cc-0d74-4a32-8cf9-87835651e1ee, 25)"
                    , "(6449fb3b-844e-440e-8973-31eb6bbefc81, 10)"}'::mytype[]);
```

I added a line break between the two row types in the array for display. That's legal.

#### How to find the correct syntax for *any* literal?

Just ask Postgres. Here is a demo:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytype (id uuid, amount numeric(13,4));

INSERT INTO mytype VALUES
  ('0d6311cc-0d74-4a32-8cf9-87835651e1ee', 25)
 ,('6449fb3b-844e-440e-8973-31eb6bbefc81', 10);

SELECT ARRAY(SELECT m FROM mytype m);
```

Returns:

```
{"(0d6311cc-0d74-4a32-8cf9-87835651e1ee,25.0000)","(6449fb3b-844e-440e-8973-31eb6bbefc81,10.0000)"}
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=af7df37e843866c9dbe97eb50099fe25)*

Any table (including temporary tables) implicitly creates a row type of the same name.

Comment: This is pure genius. Very helpful. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

```
select myschema.myfunc('0d6311cc-0d74-4a32-8cf9-87835651e1ee'
                , ARRAY[('ac747f0e-93d4-43a9-bc5b-09df06593239', '25.00')
                              , ('6449fb3b-844e-440e-8973-31eb6bbefc81', '10.00')]::mytype[]
    );
```

**Still need PHP portion of this resolved though, still not sure how to call a function populating with the custom array parameter.**