# How to pass an array of JSON (or JSON array) to pg function to be INSERTed into a Table?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, function

Function to insert rows of json array into a table:

```
create table mytable(col1 text, col2 boolean, col3 boolean);
create function fun1(vja json[])
... as $$
begin
  foreach v in array json_array_elements(vja)
  loop
    insert into mytable(col1, col2, col3)
    values(v->'col1', v->'col2'::boolean, v->'col3'::boolean);
  end loop;
end;
$$;
```

Call this function:

```
select fun1('[
    {"col1": "turow1@af.com", "col2": false, "col3": true}, 
    {"col1": "xy2@af.com", "col2": false, "col3": true} 
    ]')
```

or this form:

```
select fun1('[
    {"col1": "turow1@af.com", "col2": "false", "col3": "true"}, 
    {"col1": "xy2@af.com", "col2": "false", "col3": "true"}, 
    ]')
```

or this form:

```
select fun1('[
    {"col1": "turow1@af.com", "col2": "false", "col3": "true"}, 
    {"col1": "xy2@af.com", "col2": "false", "col3": "true"}, 
    ]'::json[])
```

Always received:

> ```
> ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[
>   {"col1": "turow1@af.com", "col2": "false", "col3": "true"}, 
>   {"col1": "xy2@af.com", "col2": "false", "col3": "true"}, 
>   ]"
> LINE 2:  '[
>          ^
> DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
> SQL state: 22P02
> Character: 136
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **JSON array** (`json`) is different from a **Postgres array of JSON values** (`json[]`).

```
SELECT '[{"foo": "bar"}, {"foo1": "bar1"}]'::json;  -- JSON array
```

vs:

```
SELECT '{"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}","{\"foo1\": \"bar1\"}"}'::json[]  -- array of JSON
```

The first is an array nested inside a single JSON value, the second is an array of JSON values.

#### Postgres array of JSON (`json[]`)

Your (fixed!) function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun1(vja json[])
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   v json;
BEGIN
   FOREACH v IN ARRAY vja
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO mytable(col1, col2, col3)
      VALUES(v ->> 'col1', (v ->> 'col2')::bool, (v ->> 'col3')::bool);
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Expects a call like this (note all the escaping for the `json[]` literal):

```
SELECT fun1('{"{\"col1\": \"turow1@af.com\", \"col2\": false, \"col3\": true}","{\"col1\": \"xy2@af.com\", \"col2\": false, \"col3\": true}"}'::json[]);
```

See:

- [How to pass custom type array to Postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009822/how-to-pass-custom-type-array-to-postgres-function/17840058#17840058)

**But** a single `INSERT` with [`json_populate_record()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in a **procedure** beats looping in a function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1(vja json[])
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$proc$
INSERT INTO mytable  -- target column list redundant in this particular case
SELECT r.*
FROM   unnest(vja) v, json_populate_record(NULL::mytable, v) r
$proc$;
```

See:

- [When to use stored procedure / user-defined function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118419/3684)

Or simpler with the standard SQL variant in **Postgres 14** or later:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1(vja json[])
BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT r.*
FROM   unnest(vja) v, json_populate_record(NULL::mytable, v) r;
END;
```

See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC ... END mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300512/3684)

Call (!):

```
CALL proc1('{"{\"col1\": \"turow1@af.com\", \"col2\": false, \"col3\": true}","{\"col1\": \"xy2@af.com\", \"col2\": false, \"col3\": true}"}'::json[]);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=22897f3f7c4fc970117ee4e742b4b524)*

#### JSON array (`json`)

Typically, you want to pass a **JSON array** like you tried.
So, now with [`json_populate_recordset()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc2(vja json)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$proc$
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset(NULL::mytable, vja);
$proc$;
```

Or (Postgres 14):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc2(vja json)
BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset(NULL::mytable, vja);
END;
```

Call (now you can use the value you originally tested with!):

```
CALL proc2('[
    {"col1": "turow1@af.com", "col2": false, "col3": true}, 
    {"col1": "xy2@af.com", "col2": false, "col3": true} 
    ]');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=22897f3f7c4fc970117ee4e742b4b524)*

Comment: Great details and recommendation!! **Q1** regarding **JSON array(`json`)** or **pg's array of JSON(`json[]`)**, If param values passed in by node API is `[{col1: 'a1@a.com', col2: false, col3: true}, {col1: 'a2@a.com', col2: false, col3: true}]`, which form to choose? **Q2** fixed function works in `public` but `operator does not exist: text ->> unknown` in others, what's missing? Thank you very much! **pg 12**

Comment: Q1: That's a JSON array (`json`). Q2: error msg indicate type `text`, where it should be  type `json`.