# Using ANY to check if any value of an array is contained in an array of enums

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table `projects` with a column `operating_sytem` which is an enum array like shown below:

[image]

Furthermore, I have an array like `['ios', 'windows']` and I want to select all the projects that have in operating_system column any value of the array
So it should return  1st, 4th, 7th and 9th occurrence

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM public.projects
WHERE operating_system = ANY (['ios', 'windows']);
```

but it returned an error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["  
> LINE 2: WHERE operating_system = ANY (['ios', 'windows']);
> ```

How can I do this query?

Comment: `...ANY (ARRAY['ios', 'windows'])`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Projects
WHERE
operating_system && ARRAY['ios', 'windows'] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the syntax of [array *constructor*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) and [array *literal*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) (*array constant*):

What's more, an array constructor would require an explicit cast, else `text` is assumed, and there is almost certainly no operator for `operation_system_enum = text` in your system.

So these would work with array constructor **if** `operating_system` was indeed a single operating system like the name implies:

```sql
... WHERE operating_system = ANY (ARRAY['ios'::operation_system_enum, 'linux']);

... WHERE operating_system = ANY (ARRAY['ios', 'linux']::operation_system_enum[]);
```

Or simpler with an (optionally untyped) array literal:

```
... WHERE operating_system = ANY ('{ios, linux}');
```

Here, the eventual type can be derived from the expression.
See:

- [How to pass custom type array to Postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009822/how-to-pass-custom-type-array-to-postgres-function/17840058#17840058)
- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause/31192557#31192557)

#### Actual answer

**But** since `operating_system` is actually type `operation_system_enum[]`, so an array of operating systems, you really need the [array "overlaps" operator **`&&`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html), like Oto suggested:

```
... WHERE operating_system && ARRAY['ios'::operation_system_enum, 'linux'];
```

Or simpler with an (untyped) array literal:

```
... WHERE operating_system && '{ios, linux}';
```

The last one is the way to go.
Only expressions with array operators can tap into a GIN index to begin with. See:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)